# I want to load some funcion while click on my button in sweet alert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I wanna load shome function while clicking on my button. I've a code for that which i've written below. Please have a look. It's working when i clicking it on confirmButton but i need to load that function when i click on my button.

```
'onClick' => "swal({
                    title: 'Scan Qr Code',
                    text: '<video id=\"preview\" width=\"100%\"></video><audio id=\"buzzer\" src=\"../beep.ogg\" type=\"audio/ogg\"></audio>',
                    html: true,
                    showCancelButton:true,
                    showConfirmButton:true,
                    allowOutsideClick:true,
                    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Scan',
                    closeOnConfirm: false 
                  }, function(){                                                                                 
                      let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
                      scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
                        $('#buzzer').get(0).play();
                        alert(content);
                      });
                      Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
                        if (cameras.length > 0) {
                          scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                        } else {
                          console.error('No cameras found.');
                        }
                      }).catch(function (e) {
                        console.error(e);
                      });
                  });
```

Comment: give more clear picture,html code of your button and full js code

Answer (score 0):

On your button click, Use jquery to check if your sweetalert is ready and execute the function.

```
'onClick' => "swal({
                title: 'Scan Qr Code',
                text: '<video id=\"preview\" width=\"100%\"></video><audio id=\"buzzer\" src=\"../beep.ogg\" type=\"audio/ogg\"></audio>',
                html: true,
                showCancelButton:true,
                showConfirmButton:true,
                allowOutsideClick:true,
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
                confirmButtonText: 'Scan',
                closeOnConfirm: false 
              });
$('#preview').ready(function(){                                                                                 
                  let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
                  scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
                    $('#buzzer').get(0).play();
                    alert(content);
                  });
                  Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
                    if (cameras.length > 0) {
                      scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                    } else {
                      console.error('No cameras found.');
                    }
                  }).catch(function (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                  });
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                 'onClick' => "swal({   
                    title: 'Scan Qr Code',
                    text: '<video id=\"preview\" width=\"100%\"></video><audio id=\"buzzer\" src=\"../beep.ogg\" type=\"audio/ogg\"></audio>',
                    html: true,
                    showCancelButton:true,
                    showConfirmButton:true,
                    allowOutsideClick:true,
                    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Scan',
                    closeOnConfirm: false 
                    }, function(){                                                                                 
                        let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
                        scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
                            $('#buzzer').get(0).play();
                            if (content.indexOf('http://') == 0 || content.indexOf('https://') == 0) {
                                return swal('Opps!!!', 'Wrong QR Code', 'error');
                            }else{
                                window.location = '/qr-search/'+content;
                            }
                        });
                        Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
                          if (cameras.length > 0) {
                            scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                          } else {
                            console.error('No cameras found.');
                          }
                        }).catch(function (e) {
                          console.error(e);
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.